# pgrouting: how to temporarily increase some edges' cost without affecting concurrent queries?

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

How to temporarily increase some edges' cost for one query without affecting other concurrent query?

The case is, I would like to develop a system that allows users to query the shortest path of a road network. Users are able to avoid some roads, what I think is to increase those road's cost temporarily for rerouting. But if I update the table directly, it will affect the original data and other concurrent queries.

Should I just use transaction to isolate the data? Is there any better way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make a pgRouting query like this one

`SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost FROM pgr_dijkstra('
                SELECT gid AS id,
                         source::integer,
                         target::integer,
                         length::double precision AS cost
                        FROM ways',
                30, 60, false, false);`

your first function argument is a `SELECT` statement, which must (in this case) return the `source`, `target` and `cost` attribute of the selected part of your network.

You can make an arbitrary query on your network table, as long as it returns the required attributes. Everything you do in this query will not change your table, but you can manipulate the selected data for example with PostgreSQL [Conditional Expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html).

`SELECT source, target, 
    CASE 
        WHEN roadtype = '1' THEN cost * 10 
        ELSE cost 
    END AS cost
FROM ways WHERE ...;`

If queries become too long or complicated, you can write a [custom function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html).